# Django use TextInput widget with ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, textinput

I'm using Django 4.2 and trying to make TextInput work with ModelMultipleChoiceField. I am using standard Django template engine and afraid that if I will have too many model objects (which will most likely happen) then SelectMultiple widget on the page will be cluttered with too many options (or even cut some of the option due to exceeding the limit) so I would like to avoid it.

I use pk as identifier for both Reports and Environments.

Ideally I would like to have frontend field which will take strings like "1, 2, 3, 4" and then convert it to pk list ([1, 2, 3, 4]) for ModelMultipleChoiceField to validate and then for form to save in DB.

This is how it looks like for now (simplified):

models.py:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    environments = models.ManyToManyField(Environment)
```

views.py:

```
class CreateReport(CreateView):
    model = Report
    form_class = ReportForm
    template_name = 'reports/new/new.html'
```

forms.py:

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['environments'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Environment.objects.all())
```

How to use widget TextInput with ModelMultipleChoiceField? Or is there maybe a better way to solve this problem with too many option (I tried searching for asynchronous JS querying the server but unfortunately didn't understand how to implement it in Django)?

Tried searching in documentation and stackoverflow for solution. Tried understanding how to include TextInput for ModelMultipleChoiceField from Django source code. Didn't figured out how to do it. What exact function will process the field response value on server? How could I overwrite it to separate string like "1, 2, 3, 4" into list of pk ([1, 2, 3, 4])?